# ViewGroup clip children can not be set false

Tags: android, android-layout, viewgroup, clip

i am trying to implement a swipeable card effect, just like the app Tinder :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tinder&hl=en_GB

When I swipe my card, the child view is always clipped by its container even if I set clipchildren and cliptopadding to false. Any idea why????

The CardStack is my custom container Layout extends RelativeLayout
xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.wenchao.cardstack.CardStack
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:clipChildren="false" <!--- false -->
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    />


<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FF00FF"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B"
        android:id="@+id/info"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/like"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dislike"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="C"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

before swipe

[image]

after swipe, the buttom of the child view is clipped :(

[image]

----------------Edit-----------------------

I found the problem is that in linear layout , the last child is always displayed on top (larger z-index). so even if cardstack container do not clip chirdren, its children are still displayed underneath the next view below. So It would better to switch to Relative layout .

But I do not really want to, because RelativeLayout do not have a nice "layout_weight" feature to specify height percentage. So the situation is that I want a way to easily control z-index (something impossible for a linearlayout) and also want to keep "layout_weight" feature (seems to be only feasible with linearlayout).  Any idea??

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need layout_weight?  I'm assuming so the top view fills all available space?  Right now you're dividing the screen into quarters, but if you can set a size on either of those views, problem solved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/large_bottom_padding"
        android:background="#FF00FF"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="B"
            android:id="@+id/info"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/like"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dislike"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="C"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.wenchao.cardstack.CardStack
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         <!-- Not really important -->
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"         <!-- Because of these lines -->
        android:layout_above="@id/button_container"  <!-- Because of these lines -->
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:clipChildren="false" <!--- false -->
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        />

</RelativeLayout
```